# How scale a Elasticbeanstalk application worker on based on messages from SQS?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I have a Scala application to do some heavy calculation based on customer_id, I'm putting customers id in SQS (Amazon Simple Queue Service), the application it is configured on ElastikBeansTalk to consume msg from SQS.

I would like to scale my application based on message coming from SQS, the problem is my application is running as HTTP server and it return 200 code after finishing the calculation, which minimum takes 15min.

SQS max timeout is 60 seconds, so after that, all msgs ended up in Dead Letter queue, I tried to send a 200 response code before finishing the calculation, but it receives another message from the queue and starts another process.

Any solution, please ?

EDIT: example of my worker configuration:
[image]

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

The max [`VisibilityTimeout`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SetQueueAttributes.html) is 12 hours. So you could put it to 30 minutes and that should cover your case.

Comment: Thank you Esardes, I increase it to 3600 seconds but when I watch my application log, it starts to consume messages without sending 200 response code, how I can make sure it only consume one single message and sqs wait until it finished ?

Comment: When you set up your Worker, you can configure the maximum number of [HTTP Connections](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html) it can make, which is the maximum number of simultaneous jobs it runs. By default it is 10, and with your jobs taking 15mins, it explains why you see it starting 10 parallel jobs simultaneously before finishing any of them. If you really want to do them one at a time set its value to 1, but beware: it will take a massive amount of time to finish all jobs if you have a lot of clients! (number of clients x 15min)

Comment: Thank you again, my application it haven't lot of clients, it'll receive max 20 customer_id on the queue / day to be processed, I change http connections to 1 and increase `Visibility timeout` to 3600 seconds, but now while processing on single message I receive it again after 62 seconds, and I keep receiving it ....
what I should so to avoid that ?

Comment: It shouldn't happen: either you have another source creating a new message in the queue after 60 seconds, you configured the wrong queue/misconfigured it, or your process returns a response to queue before it actually finished the job. Other than those, I would try to contact AWS (but I honestly doubt the issue comes from them).
Maybe start with a new queue to make sure you didn't miss a step? 
EDIT: Try changing the connection timeout to 50 secs to see if it repeats not after 62s but 52secs... (that would be weird though, but hey, debugging)

Comment: well the the issue with getting the same msg from sqs gone by setting `Max retries` to 1, but I didn't find how keep sqs wait until my app return 200 response code.
Aws Support says I should `force webserver to send the data to the client instead of buffering it,` ... `by making the application to output some text back to SQSD every 3 seconds`. I'm not sure how I can do that :/

Comment: I keep sending output throw my application but each 60 second I receive a msg from SQS without sending 200 response code yet.

Comment: It's another question in itself (one I'm not sure I can answer), but googling "deactivate output buffering [insert your webserver name here]" should yield some results.

Comment: Thank you Esardes, yes now AWS is pretty configured, I have to check how to deactivate output buffering in Scala akka Http Server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue is not from Akka HTTP Server or either from SQS,it's coming from default nginx conf. Issue resolved by editing the default proxy_read_timeout which 60s to the value desired.