# How to deactivate output buffering in Scala Akka HTTP Server

Tags: scala, akka, buffer, akka-http

I'm working on Scala application and need to deactivate the output buffering in Akka HTTP Server, I need the http server to send output each given second to avoid a timeout from the client.
I checked the configuration but didn't find how to do it.

Edit: I played around this options, but nothing also:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.11/scala/http/configuration.html

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what client timeout are we talking about here?

Comment: well it's SQSD (SQS worker from AWS), currently my application consume other msg from sqs after exactly 60 seconds, and the first msg didn't finish processing yet ( no 200 response code has been sent).

Comment: There should be no buffering. Can you add more information about what you do and where your expectations are not met?

Comment: my main question is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854611/how-scale-a-elasticbeanstalk-application-worker-on-based-on-messages-from-sqs/

Comment: currently my issue is my application consume the next msg in SQS queue after 60 seconds, and the first msg still processing,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the issue is not from Akka HTTP Server neither from SQS,it's coming from default nginx conf.
Issue resolved by editing the default `proxy_read_timeout` which `60s` to the value desired.